Did we interpret particles as excitation of fields because photons were interpreted as excitation of EM field? Was it an argument of symmetry?
When we discovered that light wave could behave as particles, we said particles then too should have wave aspects; which was the wave particle duality and it is about a symmetry of nature.

How much later did we say those 'light wave particles' (photons) are excitations of EM field? Was it immediately after?

And how does the probability aspect of finding particles fit into the picture of particles being excitation of fields? Are we calculating probability of finding the excitation somewhere? And if so, why should the excitations popping up somewhere be probabilistic in nature?



At least, in the case of photons, one does not ever "find the excitation somewhere." One finds that a bound electron somewhere (in an image sensor, a sheet of photographic film, a photomultiplier tube, etc.) has gained one photon's worth of energy. That's enough energy in some experiments, but not in all, to free the electron from its previously bound state. In either case, the existence of the photon is only ever inferred from its effect on the electron. And, the effect on the electron usually is inferred from some, more macroscopic phenomenon.
